# kg.apc.jmeter.functions.FifoTimeout does not work if added to user.properties in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am using inter thread communicator plugin to share data between two thread groups.

TG-1: generates an ID -> stores it in the queue name Q1 TG-2: picks an ID from queue -> does the processing

After some time when run duration of TG-1 is completed, it stops processing or storing ID in to Q1. TG-2 processed all the data in the queue and keep on waiting for new data in the Q1. However Q1 will not have any data. My expectation was when the run duration of TG-2 also completed. TG-2 should finish its job and exit. Why does TG-2 keep on waiting for data in Q1. This is causing the exhaustion of the heap space and test never stops. This is causing a serious issue.

To prevent this, I tried adding `kg.apc.jmeter.functions.FifoTimeout=120` in user.properties file as suggested by Dmitri T in one of my previous question for the same thing. However this property is not taking effect. Has anybody else also experience the same thing with this plugin? What is the alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are not telepathic enough to guess what is your setup, what exact components of the [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-ten-jmeter-plugins#comm) you're using and how they're configured.

If you're using [Functions](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/#Functions) - the timeout is working fine for the `__fifoPop()` function, just make sure to restart JMeter after amending the property. `__fifoGet()` one will just return an empty value if the queue is empty

If you're using [jp@gc - Inter-Thread Communication PreProcessor](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/#PostProcessor-PreProcessor) - there is a possibility to specify the timeout directly in GUI

[image]

Also it is always possible to stop the test via [Flow Control Action Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action)

[image]